# open browser from java with kyrillic charaters ( utf16 ? )

Tags: java, character-encoding

Can someone help with a String Character question ? Any ideas how to open a browser with kyrillic charaters from a java programm ?

In my JAVA Program I have a String with kyrillic characters. It is an URL, which I like to use to open a browser with 'ProcessBuilder'. The browser opens but in the url no kyrillic characters appears. Only ???????????.

Any ideas how to open a browser with kyrillic charaters from a java programm ?

regards

```
            String url = "https://www.google.ch/search?q=" + sKyrillic + "&hl=de&client=firefox-a&hs=hzU&rl......";
        try {
            new ProcessBuilder("rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler", url).start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered [Desktop.browse(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI))? In theory it should handle all the tricky stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode the value as [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). For example:

```
String cyrillic_letter_i = "\u0418";
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(cyrillic_letter_i, "UTF-8");
String google = "https://www.google.ch/search?q="
              + encoded
              + "&hl=de&client=firefox-a&hs=hzU&rl......";
URI uri = URI.create(google);
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```